# CSS2 cursor not displaying "hand"

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9, mouse-cursor

I'm following the standard of W3C here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html and here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html#note. However, the element isn't displayed the hand when mouseover. Please help.

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" onclick='javascript:window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;t=<?php single_post_title(); ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,left=300,top=100,width=626,height=436")'>[image goes here]</a>
```

When viewing with IE9 and mouseover, it doesn't change the cursor into the "hand", but it's just the regular arrow instead. Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your DOCTYPE as often IE needs to be in standards compliant mode for this sort of thing to work.

Comment: It would be much much easier to just give the anchor a `href` attribute, such as `<a href="#"` or `<a href="javascript:;"`

Comment: if i use the "#" syntax, after clicking on the img link, it "kicks" me to the top of the page, thinking there's an anchor in my page.

if i use href="javascript:;", it looks kinda ugly when mouseover :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It should be `cursor: pointer;` alone because `hand` is a proprietary value only implemented by old versions of IE, and is thus an invalid value.

If you actually care about IE 5.x, though, you switch the two properties around, i.e. (`cursor: hand; cursor: pointer`, hand comes first). Your CSS will still invalidate though, so I'd rather you not bother.

Answer (score 3):

in your supplied link:

```
Value:      [ [<uri> ,]* [ auto | crosshair | default | pointer | move | e-resize | ne-resize | nw-resize | n-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | s-resize | w-resize | text | wait | help | progress ] ] | inherit
```

`hand` is not valid css

in the other link hand is mentioned however it is only supported in ie, excluding ie9 beta, and in opera.

if you are looking for the hand with the pointing indexfinger you want `pointer` to be the last one mentioned in the css

Answer (score 3):

`hand` is not a valid value for cursor -- it is IE8- legacy. Use `pointer`.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try leaving out "cursor:hand;". According to the article you refer to, it is only needed for Internet Explorer 5. Unless you are developing a internal web app for a company who still work with that browser, I'd leave it out.